# Date Picker get Date in given timezone instead of local time

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor, momentjs, moment-timezone

In my react application, when i creating a new date object for date-picker using moment-timezone package(with different timezone), the time is automatically converting to the local system time + the chosen timezone time.
Is there any way to create a new date object with set a timezone on client side?
i am using moment-timezone for globalization and Meteor Js for back-end

Comment: It should pick up your locale settings automatically. Your server may need to have an environment setting for its timezone.

Comment: Thanks for the response @Mikkel , i couldn't understand completely, i need to create a new Date object for my date-picker in react component,how can i add my server environment to this functionality?   can you please explain more?

Comment: Just to clarify: is your date and moment related code on client or server side? And where do you use it? (On same side, or do you somehow send the date to the other side, where you see the issue?)

Comment: @ghybs i am storing users timezone into database and when a user logged in to the system the timezone fetch from db and convert all dates using moment-timezone package, i don't have any problem while showing all dates in different timezones, i have problem when i try to create a datepicker, i have to pass a new date object to the datepicker functionality, i need to create a datepicker with user timezone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, your issue is that you want to provide a Date Picker UI that automatically generates a Date object from the selected date and user time zone setting (retrieved from your database), but what you get is a date in user's local time (hence may already have some timezone offset) + the user time zone offset setting.

You have mainly 3 possible solutions:

1. Have the Date Picker UI always provide a date in UTC (typically at midnight UTC), then add your user's timezone offset setting.
2. Have the Date Picker UI take your user's timezone setting as a configuration, so that when it automatically generates a Date, it uses that timezone offset configuration.
3. Have the Date Picker UI provide a Date in the browser local time, then shift it to UTC, then add your user's timezone offset setting.

**Option 1 DatePicker in UTC:** I have not seen any library that provides such option, but it does not sound too weird, so you may find one that does. Or you may fiddle with the component code... which is probably overkill compared to option 3.

**Option 2 DatePicker with timezone configuration:** from your comment, this sounds like what you expect. Unfortunately, I have not seen any library that offers such feature either. As this sounds even more specific than option 1, it is unlikely you can find such a library.

**Option 3 local time shift to UTC then add user timezone:** this is the standard practice to achieve the objective of generating a Date in a given timezone, starting from a Date in local time, due to all DatePicker UI working just with local time to simplify things. As to shift local time to UTC, you should have plenty questions and answers on SO already.

In case you have to provide an initial value to your Date Picker UI (typically a previous value from database), then make sure to perform the reverse operation, i.e. subtract your user's timezone offset setting to get a date in UTC, then shift to browser locale time. I have seen applications that neglect this part and have incorrect date when the local time has a negative offset to UTC.

Comment: thank you very much for your explanation, I am using material-ui/DatePicker for pick FROM and TO date range for my search form. i have to set my maxDate and minDate limit for my search form. so i created 2 variable for maxDate and minDate like this,,,  var maxFromDateRange = new Date(moment.tz("user timezone").subtract(1, 'years').startOf('day'));
var maxToDateRange = new Date(moment.tz("user timezone").endOf('day')); ,,,   but when my user timezone is different from user system timezone the date picker dates will mess up ,, i couldn't configure the timezone in datepicker configuration

Comment: If I understand correctly, you would like earliest from date as today minus 1 year, and latest to date as today end of day? And to retrieve the selected dates in user timezone (as configured in db)? In that case, you can simply use the above described option 3: do not mess with timezone within the date picker or its bounds, just use browser local time. Then when using selected dates, convert from local to UTC to user tz (from db).

Comment: yes you are right, better we do not mess timezone within the date picker, what about using a datepicker that accepts the input date as a string instead of a date object, I am planning to change my material-ui/DatePicker to another datepicker, the bootstrap datepicker accept the input date as a string. what do you think about this approach?

Comment: I do not know which exact widget you refer to. Just give it a try. But I suspect it will behave as described in points 1 and 2 above, i.e. they will probably ignore timezone. E.g. old react-bootstrap-date-picker: https://github.com/pushtell/react-bootstrap-date-picker/issues/155